# AVAudioPlayer volume from variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to change the volume of a sound effect via a variable. I'm using AVAudioPlayer and calling the variable to set volume, however when I run the app I get no sound at all, regardless of the variable setting. (.1-1.0) However if I set the number from within the AvAudioPlayer block (player.volume = .5;) then it responds as it should. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Example of my code:

```
@interface

@property (nonatomic) float setVolume;

@implementation
@synthesize setVolume;

float setVolume = .5;

-(void)countdown
{
//play sound
NSString *musicFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Countdown_beep" ofType:@"wav"];
NSURL *musicURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:musicFilePath];
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicURL error:nil];
player.volume = setVolume;
[player play];
```

Thanks. :)

EDIT:

I fixed the problem by removing the declaration from the header file and creating the ivar within the implementation.

Comment: A C global (external variable) is not an ivar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line makes no sense and is irrelevant to your program:

```
float setVolume = .5;
```

You are already synthesizing a property/ivar called `setVolume`. This isn't it. So by default your property `setVolume` is zero and you are doing nothing to change that, so the volume is ending up as zero and no sound is happening.

To set the value of the property, set the value of the property. :) For example, you could say `self.setVolume = .5`. You could do that earlier in the `countdown` method, for example, or in some other method (one of the points of a property is that all methods of this object can see it).

Now, another issue with your code is that your property name begins with "set". This is probably a bad idea. If I were you, I'd pick another name. Names of the form "setX" are best used only as the name of a setter method for an instance variable / property X.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. My only problem with saying `self.setVolume = .5;` in the method is that this variable sets the volume for many instances of the sound effect being called from different methods and it's a lot more work going through and changing each one separately as opposed to just linking the volume of the AVAudioPlayer to a variable. Also I agree about avoiding 'set' in var names, I just did that here for the sake of the example code.

Comment: I guess my question then is what do I write to change the value of 'setVolume' from outside a method?

Comment: What sense could it possibly make to change the value of `setVolume` from outside a method? Methods are your code - they are what runs. Your job is to put that code in methods that will run at the correct moment. For example, if you want this to be the default value of your instance variable for every instance of this class that ever comes into existence, override the designated initializer method and set the value there. I'm a little worried that you don't understand what methods and instance variables *are*. You need to.

Comment: By setting the value of 'setVolume' outside the methods, each instance of the sound effect will receive the same volume value without me having to go in and change each one manually so in this case, of course I don't want to have the var inside a method.

Comment: By doing what I said to do (set the default value in the class's designated initializer), exactly the same thing results and you're doing it the right way. Misuse of (static) C global is not a solution, nor is a habit you should get into. If you don't want to learn, don't ask questions. :)